# PHP mysql adding to a timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I'm working in PHP with a MySQL db and I have a current timestamp field which is created when the field is made, I then have another field which (when a page is hit) I would like a SQL statement to insert a replica of the timestamp - only 2 days ahead. Any ideas on how I would go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have a table like:

```
id
current TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT..
another TIMESTAMP
```

?

You can do something like

```
UPDATE MyTable SET another = ADDDATE(current, INTERVAL 2 DAY) WHERE id = :myId
```

[MySQL Date and Time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate)

Answer (score 1):

How about `INSERT [...] (... , ADDTIME(NOW(),'2 00:00:00' , ...)`